# Python move pictures based on label

Tags: python, arrays, shutil

I have a folder contain hundreds of pictures, name as

```
Picture_1_001.png,  
Picture_1_003.png
Picture_1_010.png
Picture_1_012.png
Picture_1_014.png
and so on
```

And I have a table which look like this:

```
Col_1             Col_2
Picture_1_001.png 0
Picture_1_003.png 0
Picture_1_010.png 1
Picture_1_012.png 2
Picture_1_014.png 3
...
```

What I want to do is using the `shutil.copy()` function, move the pictures with `Col_2="0"` to folder `0`,  pictures with `Col_2="1"` to folder `1`.

What I have done was:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import shutil

isExists = os.path.exists(r'./0')

if not isExists:
    os.makedirs((r'./0'))
    os.makedirs(r'./1')
    os.makedirs(r'./2')
 

txt_file = pd.read_csv(r"./results.txt", sep = '\t',header=None)
txt_file
Col_1 Col_2
Picture_1_001.png 0
Picture_1_003.png 0
Picture_1_010.png 1
Picture_1_012.png 2
Picture_1_014.png 3
...


data_list = []
for index, rows in txt_file.iterrows():
    # Create list for the current row
    my_list =[rows.Col_1, rows.Col_2]
      
    # append the list to the final list
    data_list.append(my_list)

data_array = np.array(data_list)

source_dir ='./picture'
img = os.listdir(source_dir)

imgnum = len(img) 

for i in range(imgnum):
    label=int(data_array[i][1]) 
    print(label)

for fileNum in img:
    if not os.path.isdir(fileNum):
        imgName = os.path.join(source_dir,fileNum) 
        (imgPath, tempimagName) = os.path.split(imgName) 
        (shotname,extension) = os.path.splitext(tempimagName) 

    tempimagName='%s.png'%shotname
    imgName=os.path.join('./picture/',tempimagName)
    shutil.copy(imgName,'./'+str(label)+'/'+tempimagName)
```

This made all pictures go to the same folder not split. How can I split my pictures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is issue in the following section:

```
for i in range(imgnum):
    label=int(data_array[i][1]) 
    print(label)
```

as you are setting a final value for label and using it in the last loop. You can use an iterator for the label as well and use that in the copy line.

Following may not be the best way to do this but you can get the idea:

```
label = []
for i in range(imgnum):
    label.append(int(data_array[i][1]))

i=0
for fileNum in img:
    if not os.path.isdir(fileNum):
        imgName = os.path.join(source_dir,fileNum) 
        (imgPath, tempimagName) = os.path.split(imgName) 
        (shotname,extension) = os.path.splitext(tempimagName) 
    
    lbl = str(label[i])
    i+=1
    
    tempimagName='%s.png'%shotname
    imgName=os.path.join('./picture/',tempimagName)
    shutil.copy(imgName,'./'+lbl+'/'+tempimagName)
```

Comment: It looks like an indentation problem in this example.

Comment: @RufusVS Thanks! I tried correcting it earlier but missed. Corrected now.

Comment: @sacse Thank you so much. It works perfectly!